# xslt transformation to copy from xml to xml specific nodes omly

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to create a sub-xml of some xml file. 
I have a list of required nodes. How xslt tranformation should look like? 
For example, input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <a id="A">
    <aa>text</aa>
    <bb>text</bb>
    <cc id="1">
      <aaa>text</aaa>
      <bbb>text</bbb>
    </cc>
  </a>
  <a id="B">
    <aa>text2</aa>
    <bb>text2</bb>
    <cc id="2">
      <aaa>text2</aaa>
      <bbb>text2</bbb>      
    </cc>
  </a>
</root>
```

desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <a id="A">
      <bb>text</bb>
      <cc>
         <bbb>text</bbb>
      </cc>
   </a>
   <a id="B">
      <bb>text2</bb>
      <cc>
         <bbb>text2</bbb>
      </cc>
   </a>
</root>
```

Currently I use follwonf xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*"/>

  <xsl:template match="
 root
|root/a
|root/a/@id
|root/a/bb
|root/a/bb/node()
|root/a/cc
|root/a/cc/bbb
|root/a/cc/bbb/node()
 ">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I would like to have shorter list something like that:

```
 root/a/@id
|root/a/bb/node()
|root/a/cc/bbb/node()
```

So how to create xslt transformation for that short list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in XSLT 2.0 you could use a variable with those nodes, compute the ancestors in another variable and then use those variables as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="copy"
        select="
        root/a/@id
        |root/a/bb/node()
        |root/a/cc/bbb/node()"/>

    <xsl:variable name="subtrees" select="$copy/ancestor-or-self::node()"/>

    <xsl:template match="*[. intersect $subtrees]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*[. intersect $copy]"/>               
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[. intersect $subtrees]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In XSLT 3.0 using a [static parameter](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#static-params) and a [shadow attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#shadow-attributes) you could even parameterize it further:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:param name="paths" static="yes" as="xs:string"
        select="'root/a/@id | root/a/bb/node() | root/a/cc/bbb/node()'"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="copy" _select="{$paths}"/>

    <xsl:variable name="subtrees" select="$copy/ancestor-or-self::node()"/>

    <xsl:template match="*[. intersect $subtrees]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*[. intersect $copy]"/>               
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[. intersect $subtrees]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I need. I don't know how that magic works but it works and it is a main thing for me right now!

Answer (score 0):

I would get more specific:

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@id|bb|cc"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cc">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="bbb"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 1.0 I would propose the following transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:if test="not(. = following-sibling::*)">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It selects every last node wich has identical value.